# Object/Associative Array Splice function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know about the **splice** function for arrays but in Java script **Associative arrays** are not allowed hence i have to use another method which involves using objects.Which is declared by this code `var check={};`

For instance,I wanna use the Splice method for my *ObjectArray*.How am i supposed to achieve the same as *splice method* but with **associative array**?

**Data:**

```
Object {mad over donuts: "company", dunkin donuts: "company"}
```

Comment: there no such thing as "associative array" in JavaScript

Comment: please add some data, and how to "*splice*" them.

Comment: @Werner — The question says "object" and uses the object literal as a code example. It isn't a NodeList.

Comment: Yes, you can call the array prototype to achieve your case.

Comment: You can call splice as **Array.prototype.splice.call(check, your_arguments)**

Comment: @PrasannaRkv — Which won't do anything (except add a length property to the object) because a plain object is not sufficiently Array-like for it to function. http://jsbin.com/baxanaz/1/edit?js,console

Comment: how do i delete that dunkin donuts part? @Quentin

Comment: @Quentin -  objects will not behave good with this unless you have a check.length. but it will play like array only it will splice only keys of numerals not work on the strings as he given now. forgot to add this.

Comment: @PrasannaRkv — The point of the question is that the properties aren't numeric.

Comment: @Pinkman read @Quentins answer. `delete myObject.foo;`

Comment: @Quentin use as ***delete check['dunkin donuts part']*** for the keys with spaces

Comment: @Quentin for non numeric, we have to go with delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to use `splice` on an object.

`splice` removes a range of properties from an array and then inserts a set of values in the same place.

Properties in an object, unlike in an array, *have no order*. You can't remove everything between X and Y because there isn't anything there.

Insert new properties by assigning values to them.

```
myObject.foo = bar;
```

Remove properties by deleting them.

```
delete myObject.foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no time to test the bellow code but I think it might help you.

```
var myObjArray = {
   'bad donut' : 'company',
   'good donut': 'company',
   'very good donut': 'company',
   'very very good donut': 'company',
}

function splice(pArray, pIndex, pNumber) {
   var removed = [];
   Objects.keys(pArray).forEach(function(key, index, array) {
      if (index >= pIndex && index <= pIndex + pNumber) {
         removed.push(pArray[key]);
         delete pArray[key];
      }
   });

   return removed;
}

var element_removed = splice(myObjArray, 2, 1);

/* should let the array be : 
   'bad donut' : 'company',
   'good donut': 'company',
   'very very good donut': 'company',
*/
```

But I don't really know if it make sense because associative array can be sorted and the index change. splice is not something you should looking for.

Maybe you should tell us what you want for result ?

Comment: i was looking for something like this only.I had two check boxes on which i had a `onchange` listener so when someone checks it, the id of the checked item goes to the index of the object array and the name of the check boes to the value of the corresponding index .Now when someone unchecks the check box i wanted it to remove the correspondind index i.e. the id of the check box from this object array.

Comment: Is it what you looked for ? If yes valid the answer, if no, tell me what you need in addition of this code.